# running comparisons and statistical tests in parallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

on a HPC cluster, I would like to run in parallel the following operations :

```
wilcox.test(DAY1C4$analyte_value, DAY8C4$analyte_value)
wilcox.test(DAY1C8$analyte_value, DAY8C8$analyte_value)
wilcox.test(DAY1TG$analyte_value, DAY8TG$analyte_value)
```

I do use the following libraries :

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(boot)
library(doParallel)

numCores <- detectCores()
numCores
cl <- makeCluster(numCores)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, we do. Although the comparisons above are for the start. I would like to run on separate CPU each comparison : on CPU1 : wilcox.test(DAY1.C4$analyte_value, DAY8.C4$analyte_value); 
on CPU2 : wilcox.test(DAY1.C8$analyte_value, DAY8.C8$analyte_value)

Comment: yes, that is right, at different days DAY1 and DAY8. I will re-write the question. Essentially it it is only a wilcox.test between pairs of lists.

Comment: wonderful, thank you very much ! It works smoothly ! With much appreciation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `future_map2`

```
furrr::future_map2(day1list, day8list, wilcox.test)
```

where

```
day1list <- list(DAY1C4$analyte_value, DAY1C8$analyte_value, DAY1TG$analyte_value)
day8list <- list(DAY8C4$analyte_value, DAY8C8$analyte_value, DAY8TG$analyte_value)
```